# How to avoid out of memory python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, out-of-memory, data-science, cluster-analysis

I'm new to python and ubuntu. i got `killed` after running python code. The file I'm using for the code is around 2.7 GB and I have 16 GB RAM with one tera hard ... what should I do to avoid this problem because I'm searching and found it seems to be out of memory problem

I used this command

```
free -mh
```

I got

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        15G        2.5G        9.7G        148M        3.3G         12G
Swap:       4.0G        2.0G        2.0G
```

the code link I tried [Link](https://github.com/freesinger/density_peak_clustering)

```
 import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class ProcessData(object):
    def data_process(self, folder):
        '''
        :folder: data file path
        :rtype: dict pair distance
                MAX id number
        '''
        distance = dict()
        max_pt = 0
        with open(folder, 'r') as data:
            for line in data:
                i, j, dis = line.strip().split()
                i, j, dis = int(i), int(j), float(dis)
                distance[(i, j)] = dis
                distance[(j, i)] = dis
                max_pt = max(i, j, max_pt)
            for num in range(1, max_pt + 1):
                distance[(num, num)] = 0
        return distance, max_pt

    def entropy(self, distance, maxid, factor):
        '''
        :distance: dict with pair: dist
        :factor: impact factor
        :maxid: max elem number
        :rtype: entropy H in data field
        '''
        potential = dict()
        for i in range(1, maxid + 1):
            tmp = 0
            for j in range(1, maxid + 1):
                tmp += np.exp(-pow(distance[(i, j)] / factor, 2))
            potential[i] = tmp
        z = sum(potential.values())
        H = 0
        for i in range(1, maxid + 1):
            x = potential[i] / z
            H += x * np.log(x)
        return -H

    def threshold(self, dist, max_id):
        '''
        :rtype: factor value makes H smallest
        '''
        entro = 10.0
        # given data:
        # 0.02139999999999999 7.203581306901208
        # 0.02149999999999999 7.203577254067677
        # 0.02159999999999999 7.203577734107922

        # generate data:
        # 0.367020, 6.943842
        # 0.368959, 6.943840
        # 0.370898, 6.943841
        
        scape = np.linspace(0.330, 0.430, 50)
        # 通用数据使用以下一行
        # scape = np.linspace(0.001, 1.001, 100)
        for factor in scape:
            value = self.entropy(dist, max_id, factor)
            print('factor: {0:.6f}, entropy: {1:.8f}'.format(factor, value))
            # plt.scatter(factor, value, c='r', s=1)
            if value and value < entro:
                entro, thresh = value, factor
        thresh = 3 * thresh / pow(2, 0.5)
        
        """
        plt.xlabel(r'$\sigma$')
        plt.ylabel(r'H')
        plt.savefig('./images/Entropy test.png')
        plt.close()
        """

        print('current: ', entro, thresh)
        # given data:  7.203577254067677 0.04560838738653229
        # generate data: 6.943840312796875 0.7828967189629044
        return thresh
    
    def CutOff(self, distance, max_id, threshold):
        '''
        :rtype: list with Cut-off kernel values by desc
        '''
        cut_off = dict()
        for i in range(1, max_id + 1):
            tmp = 0
            for j in range(1, max_id + 1):
                gap = distance[(i, j)] - threshold
                tmp += 0 if gap >= 0 else 1
            cut_off[i] = tmp
        sorted_cutoff = sorted(cut_off.items(), key=lambda k:k[1], reverse=True)
        return sorted_cutoff
            
    def Guasse(self, distance, max_id, threshold):
        '''
        :rtype: list with Gaussian kernel values by desc
        '''
        guasse = dict()
        for i in range(1, max_id + 1):
            tmp = 0
            for j in range(1, max_id + 1):
                tmp += np.exp(-pow((distance[(i, j)] / threshold), 2))
            guasse[i] = tmp
        sorted_guasse = sorted(guasse.items(), key=lambda k:k[1], reverse=True)
        return sorted_guasse

    def min_distance(self, distance, srt_dens, maxid):
        '''
        :srt_dens: desc sorted list with density values (point, density)
        :rtype: min distance dict
                min number dict
        '''
        min_distance = dict()
        min_number = dict()
        h_dens = srt_dens[0][0]
        min_number[h_dens] = 0
        max_dist = -1
        for i in range(1, maxid + 1):
            max_dist = max(distance[(h_dens, i)], max_dist)
        min_distance[h_dens] = max_dist
        
        for j in range(1, len(srt_dens)):
            min_dist, min_num = 1, 0
            current_num = srt_dens[j][0]
            for k in srt_dens[0:j]:
                current_dist = distance[(current_num, k[0])]
                if current_dist < min_dist:
                    min_dist, min_num = current_dist, k[0]
            min_distance[srt_dens[j][0]] = min_dist
            min_number[current_num] = min_num
        return min_distance, min_number

    def make_pair(self, srt_dens, min_dist, maxid):
        '''
        :rtype: pair dict with {point: [density, min dist]}
                refer factor dict with {point: density * dist}
        '''
        pair_dict = dict()
        dens_dict = dict()
        refer_dict = dict()
        # convert list to dict
        for elem in srt_dens:
            dens_dict[elem[0]] = elem[1]
        if len(dens_dict) == maxid:
            for key in dens_dict.keys():
                pair_dict[key] = [dens_dict[key], min_dist[key]]
                refer_dict[key] = dens_dict[key] * min_dist[key]
        else:
            return print('missing %d value', maxid - dens_dict)
        return pair_dict, refer_dict
    
    def show_pair_info(self, pair, threshold):
        show_dict = dict()
        for p in pair.values():
            show_dict[p[0]] = p[1]
        tmp = sorted(show_dict.items())
        dens, mdis = zip(*tmp)
        plt.scatter(dens, mdis)
        plt.xlabel(r'$\rho$')
        plt.ylabel(r'$\delta$')
        plt.title(r'$d_c=$' + str(threshold))
        plt.savefig('./images/Decision Graph Cutoff test.png')
        plt.close()
```

I tried to figure by using fil-profile and got a problem with line 11 which indicate  this [data_process](https://github.com/freesinger/density_peak_clustering/blob/master/data_process.py)

Comment: I'm afraid that the implementation of that library is not as optimal and thus consumes big chunks of memory. Maybe this SO answer can help you to identify what parts of the program consume too much memory and find more efficient solutions (i.e. patch the original code to be more memory efficient): https://stackoverflow.com/a/552810/2402281

Comment: thanks for replying but what did you mean by SO .. i tried to figure by using fil-profile and got a problem with line 11 which indicate to data_process

Comment: SO is the abbreviation for StackOverflow.

Comment: I got it after little search :-) thanks .. if you can help I edit the post with the code that need to be handle

Answer (score 0):

An issue could be `f.readlines()` as it creates a complete list.

So if `COOR_DATA` is very large then you should only create memory for one line at a time, so try changing:

```
with open(COOR_DATA, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    coords = dict()
    for line in lines:
```

To:

```
with open(COOR_DATA, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    coords = dict()
    for line in f:
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: thank for helping I did it now but the problem still, I tried to figure where is the problem as I mentioned in the update post

Comment: How can the "problem" be narrow down? In principle we should be able to move the data to any kind of memory and process it. What do we know about the bottleneck? Any particular function?