# How to find "nearest neighbors" in a list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy

My objective is the following: given a list of numbers (int. or float) (1D), I need to find *N* amount of numbers that are closest to
each other in this list. For example:

Given `sample_list = [1, 8, 14, 15, 17, 100, 35]` and `N = 3`, the desired function should return a list of `[14, 15, 17]`, because the 3 "nearest neighbors" in this list are 14, 15, and 17.

So far, I have tackled the problem the following way, being forced to make **several compromises** in my approach (after unsuccessfully searching for a solution online):

I decided to iterate over each number in the list and find its *N* amount of "nearest neighbors". These "nearest neighbors" are stored in a new list and then compared with other such lists using [numpy.diff](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) function. The list with the smallest amount resulted from `numpy.diff` is the winner.

At the base of my solution is the code provided by [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-closest-number-to-k-in-given-list/) on geeksforgeeks.org. The idea to use `numpy.diff` function came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172933/calculate-difference-between-adjacent-items-in-a-python-list) on stackoverflow.com

My (working) monstrosity can be found below:

```py
import numpy as np
def find_nn_in_list_1D(list_for_search, num_neighbors_desired):

        list_iterator = list_for_search.copy()

        list_mod = list_for_search.copy()

        neighbor_storage_list = []

        neighbor_eval_score = 999_999_999
                
        for number in list_iterator:
                
                neighbor_nil = list_mod[min(range(len(list_mod)), key = lambda i: abs(list_mod[i] - number))]
                
                neighbor_storage_list.append(neighbor_nil)

                list_mod.remove(neighbor_nil)
        
                for num_neighbor in range(num_neighbors_desired):
                
                        neighbor = list_mod[min(range(len(list_mod)), key = lambda i: abs(list_mod[i] - number))]
                                
                        neighbor_storage_list.append(neighbor)
                                
                        list_mod.remove(neighbor)
                
                neighbor_storage_list.sort()

                if neighbor_eval_score > abs(sum(np.diff(neighbor_storage_list))):
                                
                        neighbor_eval_score = abs(sum(np.diff(neighbor_storage_list)))
                        
                        nearest_neighbors_list = neighbor_storage_list.copy()
                                                        
                list_mod = list_for_search.copy()
                        
                neighbor_storage_list = []

        return nearest_neighbors_list
```

I am very certain that there is **a much better way** of solving this issue.

Even though it works, I would like to write better, cleaner code.

If you have a better solution than mine please share below. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work -

```
import numpy as np

N = 3
X = np.array([1, 8, 14, 15, 17, 100, 35]).astype(np.float32)

d = np.abs(X[None, :] - X[:, None])
np.fill_diagonal(d, np.inf)

min_array = d.min(0)

par = np.argpartition(min_array, N)

print(X[par[:N]])
```

This gives -

`[14. 15. 17.]`

First you create a matrix of differences between every pair of elements. You can then choose the `n` least differences out of it and use that to find the indices of the elements you are looking for. Just make sure to mask out the diagonal elements of the matrix becasue they are always going to be zero (since they will represent the distance between every point to itself).

Comment: Hello Ananda! Could you please clarify the `par = np.argpartition(min_array, N)`. I am with you until that line, but struggling to understand this function's role.

Comment: That finds the index of the smallest N numbers in the input. `par[:N]` will be `[2, 3, 4]` in this case, which means that in `min_array` the smallest three elements are in the index `[2, 3, 4]`. Simply pick those values from the original `X` and that's your solution.

Comment: If your question is resolved, please consider closing it by accepting an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If there is no particular dependency on `numpy` - we could solve this with some *comprehensions* as well -

```
lst = [1, 8, 14, 15, 17, 100, 35]

#Make pairs and remove duplicates using a set
lst_pairs = set([tuple(sorted((x, y))) for x in lst for y in lst if x != y])

#Make a dictionary mapping a pair to distance
dist_dict = {k: k[1] - k[0] for k in lst_pairs}

#extract the top 3 by distance
nearest_n = sorted(dist_dict, key=lambda x: dist_dict[x])[:3]

#unpack the pairs to unique points
nearest_n_pts = set([pt for pair in nearest_n for pt in pair])

#nearest_n_pts is [14, 15, 17]
```